# How to map return-type to base64binary in Zend SOAP-server?

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap

I need to use the Zend-framework to build a SOAP-server (WSDL-mode) and return binary data using xsi:type="xsd:base64binary" in the answer. It seems like Zend doesn't support base64binary as a return-type.

How can I tell Zend to use base64binary to wrap around my string containing base64_encoded binary data?

Thanks, Stefan.